# Substitute peanut butter for cookie butter?

Tags: baking, substitutions

I'm trying to make mug cookies and it calls for cookie butter, which I don't have. Can I use peanut butter instead?

Comment: The cookie butter I've heard of is basically spreadable speculoos/gingersnaps (i.e. ground up cookies plus oil to make it spreadable). Is that likely to be what your recipe is talking about? (Could you just post/link to the recipe?)

Comment: The consistency is essentially the same; given the small size of most mug recipes, I think it would be worth making one to see how it turns out.

Answer (score 2):

Peanut butter and cookie butter are quite different in taste: your end-result will be very different as well.

To make your own cookie butter, take 66% gingerbread cookies, 33% unsalted butter (left out of the fridge) and mix into a paste.

That being said: if you *really like* peanut butter and you're making this for yourself: go for it: the texture is about the same.  I would add a bit of honey or jam to the peanut butter as well as cookie butter is a bit sweeter then peanut butter.